# Android C2DM LAST_REGISTRATION_CHANGE ?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have a problem writing an application which uses C2DM service. Everything works OK, but I'm worried that the registration id may change and as I send it to my server, I want to send a good registration id. 
When user logs in, I send a request and get a registration id. Until user is logged in, C2DM must work. But can I actually check if the registration id was updated, so I can send it to the server again? I know there is something like `LAST_REGISTRATION_CHANGE`, but that's all... Any ideas on how to compare current registration id with a last one (or something like that)? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to get new REG_ID when it's changed i.e from C2DM receiver

Comment: no, I'm not. I get REG_ID only once and then I don't check for updates... You mean I should 'listen' to broadcast receiver all the time and update the REG_ID I have when a new one will come? Could You please post some example code on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: yes u r right do this way... If any problems then I would post the code.. Otherwise you can simply achieve that

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I'm saving a REG_ID in SharedPreferences while Logging and then if the user is already Logged, I check if REG_ID from SharedPreferences is different than the one from Receiver. It seems that it works property. Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 1):

So finally your problem is solved : I am enclosing a portion of code of receiver for others help.

*

```
public class C2DMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private Context context;
        private String key;
        private String textExpand;
        private String text;
        private boolean flag = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            this.context = context;
            Log.e("TAG", "Action : " + intent.getAction());
            Set<String> set = intent.getExtras().keySet();

            Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                key = iterator.next();
                Log.v("TAG", key + " : " + intent.getStringExtra(key));
    }
```

}
        }

*